# Como puedo optimizar o cual sería la mejor forma de hacer este tipo de función?

Tags: javascript, optimización

Hola, soy Trainee en JS, hice un curso en Coderhouse, quería consultar cual sería la mejor forma de hacer este tipo de función, si la mía esta bien o mal, siento que esta mal por usar muchos if, pero funcionar me funciona.
(Se que esta mal combinar JQuery con JS Vanilla, pero esta función la hice así nomás hoy porque mi hermano me pidió que lo haga para su portfolio)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    const proyectos = document.getElementById("proyectos");
    const sobreMi = document.getElementById("sobreMi");
    const projects = document.getElementById("projects").getBoundingClientRect().y;
    const about = document.getElementById("about").getBoundingClientRect().y;
    console.log(about);
    if (projects < 0) {
      proyectos.classList.add("scroll-secondary-title");
    }
    if (projects > 0) {
      proyectos.classList.remove("scroll-secondary-title");
    }
    if (about < 370) {
      proyectos.classList.remove("scroll-secondary-title");
    }
    if (about < 150) {
      sobreMi.classList.add("scroll-secondary-title");
    }
    if (about > 150) {
      sobreMi.classList.remove("scroll-secondary-title");
    }if (($(window).innerHeight() + $(window).scrollTop()) >= $("body").height()) {
      sobreMi.classList.remove("scroll-secondary-title");
    }
  });
```

Básicamente lo que hace esta función es que le agrega una clase a determinados elementos dependiendo en que parte del scrollY estas posicionado. De que otra manera lo puedo hacer y que quede como más "limpio"?

Comment: Quieres que quede más limpio? Deja de mezclar español e inglés y utiliza nombres que expresen significado de lo que realmente es la variable. `proyectos` y `projects` significan lo mismo, sin embargo `projects` es un número mientras que su versión española es un elemento... por qué no `projects` para el elemento y `projectsHeight` para el alto? Más claro y dentro de cinco meses de un vistazo seguirás sabiendo lo que es cada cosa. En cuanto a la cantidad de `if`... un código que hace muchas cosas tiene que llevar muchos `if`, es inevitable. Lo que podrías hacer es "romperlo" en más partes ...

Comment: O directamente mover todos esos `if` a una función privada y ahí simplemente invocarla. En realidad solo estás moviendo los condicionales a otra parte, pero cuando entras a la función queda mejor ver un `handleClasses()` que un montón de condicionales. O directamente, pasar al evento el handler de la función: `window.addEventListener("scroll", handleClasses);`, no tienes por qué poner ahí mismo la función. Y sobre todo, en vez de poner dos `if` para la misma condición... usa el `else` para eliminar la clase! `if (projects < 0) {...} else { ... }`

Comment: Saca las variables `proyectos, sobreMi, projects, about` fuera del callback. Así no tienes que buscar los elementos por cada scroll.